# Compile C++ code, then un-compile it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation

When I write code in c++, and compile using Visual Studio (Microsofts compiler), the resulting assembly does some optimization to my code.

I wanted to create a program, for learning (or teaching others), that takes c++ code, compiles it, then converts that optimized code back into c++ to show what was optimized (via a diff program)

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Google "disassembler"

Comment: You need an *unpiler*. I'm not sure if one exists, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opensource C/C++ decompiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711220/opensource-c-c-decompiler)

Comment: @Angew Since I am using Visual Studio, can't I instruct it to output the assembly (instead of machine code) and thus not need a dissasembler for that bit?

Comment: [Boomerang decompiler](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/). But good luck making it work :/

Comment: Decompilers definitely exist, they're just not good for what OP wants to do.

Comment: The closest thing to what you want is compiling C++ to LLVM IR, optimising it and then compiling back into plain obfuscated C using C backend (it's only available in the old LLVM versions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no 1:1 mapping between C++ and optimized code, so the resulting code will probably always look different then you expect. One thing you can do is, to instruct the compiler to outpout the assembly source `(-S option)` and look what the compiler did. First without optimizations and then with them enabled, so you can see the differences.

Comment: This seems like the best solution. Apparently I can't go backwards, but with VS I can at least spit out the un-optimized and optimized code, and do the diff there, hoping everyone understands assembly!

Comment: Yes, that's the best way to go, because you have full control over the prpocess and can see the differences. You can start with a small well defined function and then you can see how the output changes when you modify it. For learning purposes you could even write a simple GUI, which calls the compiler and then shows the differences side by side.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Nobody has ever created such tool.

In general optimized code cannot be converted back to C++. Optimization works with intermediate representation that looks like assembler. For example optimizer may merge parts of functions if they look similar. How can you represent this in C++? If you will duplicate merged parts, this will not be the true representation of the code. There are several other cases like that with temp variables, control flow conversions (jumps from if-else and similar), subexpression eliminations, and others.

The best what you can do is print assembler and try to understand what is going on in the code. I would recommend you to play with small 3-5 lines functions and compare assembler listings after small modification of your function. Comparing difference in the function to the difference in assembler code often tells a lot.

Some time ago I came across "linker optimization". There were several absolutely identical functions in my program (this was needed) that linker decided to merge into one. Nothing was working until I understood that.

Comment: Damn! Do you know why it's not possible? Is the assembly generate just not anything c++ would understand, as in very specific to assembly?

Comment: @MintyAnt because there is no one-to-one mapping between C++ source code and asembly code. It is a many-to-one, or even many-to-many mapping.

Comment: Unfortunate, but I believe that makes sense. Do you happen to know what I could research to see a few examples of this optimization? @kirill you mentioned merging functions, I would love to see how the c code compared to assembly looks for that, if such an article exists!

Comment: Not all compiler optimizations can be translated back to C++. Some of them are *pipeline* optimizations: fiddling with the order of separate instructions may yield in a better CPU throughput. Intel has a manual on its website with all the gory details.